# Issue changing product image size - Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

I want to have slightly larger product images on the product detail page. And this is what I have done:

- New custom layout with min-height for product image set to 550px
- Edit the Product Media folder settings with a new size for thumbnails: 550x550px
- Edit the funktion `sw-thumbnails` with sizes (view file cms-element-image-gallery.html.twig). Like this:

```
{% sw_thumbnails 'gallery-slider-image-thumbnails' with {
    media: image,
    sizes: {
      'xs': '501px',
      'sm': '400px',
      'md': '470px',
      'lg': '500px',
      'xl': '550px',
    }
} %}
```

But it seems to only works sometimes. Some products keeps the old size and just adding some white space around. I have a local store with some demo products, and I have tried clearing the cache (not helping).

When I edit the thumbnails size list, do I need to do something to have Shopware recreate the thumbnails to the new sizes? Or is it done automagically?

Shopware 6

Comment: Is this about Shopware 6 or Shopware 5? Please correct the tag

Comment: This is about Shopware 6. The tag was correct, but added "Shopware 6" in my question.

Comment: The title said Shopware 5 - fixed it :-)

Comment: Are there any custom templates or CSS? maybe that causes the whitespace. Did you verify the actual image file served by the server?

Comment: Yes, I have some custom CSS - but nothing that should influence the gallery image. No matter how I raise the minimun height, the image never gets bigger then 454px. (and now, even the product that worked before, dont change size). In Safari web inspector I can see that the top margin just gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [CLI command](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/shopware-cli) to re-generate the thumbnails:

```
bin/console media:generate-thumbnails
```

To only re-generate product media thumbnails, you can provide the name of the specific folder.

```
bin/console media:generate-thumbnails --folder-name "Product Media"
```

Comment: Thanks.
But this is confusing ;)
I did run the commands (on Product Media) and thumbnails was recreated. But no change on the front.

Anyway, I have to stick to the default sizes. For now at least.